# Little advance mysql order by query

Tags: mysql

I use following working mysql query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabs  
ORDER BY 
    featured desc, 
    CASE WHEN  city='$city' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
    hits DESC
```

It returns the data order by featured first and then rows has city values and then hits.

The database table 'tabs' has  following order

1. id(int)
2. city(text)
3. tabname(text)
4. hits(int)
5. featured (int)

how I can get data order by featured in city first then other data from city then order by hits

for example

If i live in Rome and I want data to return in this order. All tabs comes first which has city='Rome' and featured='1',  and then other tabs from Rome (same city city='Rome'), and then hits desc.

I have tried following but failed :

```
SELECT *
FROM tabs  
ORDER BY 
    featured desc, 
    CASE WHEN  featured='1' and city='$city' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
    CASE WHEN city='$city' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
    hits DESC
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39ccd/6/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a try with this one:

```
SELECT * FROM tabs  
ORDER BY featured desc, 
CASE WHEN featured='1' and city='$city' THEN 0
     WHEN featured='0' and city='$city' THEN 1
ELSE 2 END, 
hits DESC
```

Comment: i little changed and it worked fine SELECT * FROM tabs  
ORDER BY  
CASE WHEN featured='1' and city='$city' THEN 0
     WHEN featured='0' and city='$city' THEN 1
ELSE 2 END, 
featured desc, hits DESC